# hive -h <hostname> not establishing connection to hive console

Tags: hadoop, hive

While inputing:

`hive -h <hostname>`

From hdfs command line I am not getting directed to hive console.

Still being asked for Hostname to be entered.

```
'Choose Hive Server/Metastore Hostname from : <hostname>'
'Enter Hive Server/Metastore Hostname :'
```

If the hostname is getting submitted using command hive -h  then ideally it should not ask for hostname again.

Answer (score 0):

Using Hive 3, the output I get from hive -h hostname is help that does not mention a -h option. Using beeline to specify a hostname works for me:

```
[me@myhost-1 ~]$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://myhost-2.com:10000
...
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://myhost.com:10000
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.0.3.0-192)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.0.3.0.3.0-192)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 3.1.0.3.0.3.0-192 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://myhost-2.com:>
```

Help output also includes other beeline examples to connect to Hive:

```
Example:
    1. Connect using simple authentication to HiveServer2 on localhost:10000
    $ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 username password

    2. Connect using simple authentication to HiveServer2 on hs.local:10000 using -n for username and -p for password
    $ beeline -n username -p password -u jdbc:hive2://hs2.local:10012

    3. Connect using Kerberos authentication with hive/localhost@mydomain.com as HiveServer2 principal
    $ beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://hs2.local:10013/default;principal=hive/localhost@mydomain.com"

    4. Connect using SSL connection to HiveServer2 on localhost at 10000
    $ beeline "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default;ssl=true;sslTrustStore=/usr/local/truststore;trustStorePassword=mytruststorepassword"

    5. Connect using LDAP authentication
    $ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://hs2.local:10013/default <ldap-username> <ldap-password>
```

Using two hyphens, not one, is the correct syntax:

```
hive --help
Usage ./hive <parameters> --service serviceName <service parameters>
Service List: beeline cleardanglingscratchdir cli fixacidkeyindex help hiveburninclient hiveserver2 hplsql jar lineage llapdump llap llapstatus metastore metatool orcfiledump rcfilecat schemaTool strictmanagedmigration tokentool version 
Parameters parsed:
  --auxpath : Auxiliary jars 
  --config : Hive configuration directory
  --service : Starts specific service/component. cli is default
Parameters used:
  HADOOP_HOME or HADOOP_PREFIX : Hadoop install directory
  HIVE_OPT : Hive options
For help on a particular service:
  ./hive --service serviceName --help
Debug help:  ./hive --debug --help
```

Comment: Error message: 'Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri'

Comment: Are you using an old version of hive? In Hive 0.9.0 hive -H or hive --help returned the help. Please see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveCLI

Comment: Use two hypens --help.